is there way to add inputText into Datatable and update all datatable inputTests in one shot outside the table ? (primefaces) JSF
iam using java primefaces,
i have Datatable contains InputText in each row,
i need to update database based on inputText for all rows in one button,
currently i have add a listener for each inputText but this is not user friendly ...
<p:column headerText="#{msg.get('evQuestionMark')}" style="FONT-SIZE: 15px ;color: darkblue; text-align: center;">

 <h:outputText rendered="#{!question.firstMarkEditable}" value="#{question.firstQuestionMark==null?msg.get('clickToChoose'):question.firstQuestionMark}  " style="FONT-SIZE: 15px ; text-align: center;">      
 </h:outputText>
 

 <pe:inputNumber id="firstQuestionMark2" type="number" autocomplete="false" maxValue="#{question.evQuestionMaxMark}" value="#{mbEvaluation.questionEmp.firstQuestionMark}" rendered="#{question.firstMarkEditable}" style="FONT-SIZE: 15px ;width:50px">
       <p:ajax event="blur" process="@this" update="questionTable" listener="#{mbEvaluation.updateFirstLevel()}">
       </p:ajax>
 </pe:inputNumber>
</p:column>

many thanks in advance.

Which problem exactly are you facing when you simply follow your own instructions and replace the <p:ajax> inside the input component by the desired <p:commandButton> outside the table?
